# Sequence is reusing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequence

I have a sequence that generates tracking numbers for objects in my system.  It had been working fine for quite some time.

Last week we noticed that it was starting to re-use values.

What seems to happen is that at different points in the evening, it will rollback to a value it had the previous day.  It will then continue generating values from that point.

So for example I could get something like this:

> 10112
>   **10113**
>   10114
>   10115
>   10116
>   10117
>   10118
>   **10113**
>   10114
>   10115
>   10116
>   ...

There does not seem to be any pattern in when it happens, duration between the first use and second use (as few as 10 min or several hours) or how many are rolled back (as few as 1 and as many as several hundred).

I thought about running a trace (and still may), but I don't think the sequence object is being directly modified.  The reason I believe this is that the modify date is several days old and points to a time when we manually bumped the value up to try and eliminate duplicates.  (And the issue has occurred several times since then.)

**Does anyone have an idea of what could cause a sequence rollback and reuse values each night?**

UPDATE: To answer a few questions in the comments:

- `@@Version`:

  > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) Oct 19 2012 13:38:57
- Create Script:

  ```
  CREATE SEQUENCE [schemaName].[SequenceName] 
    AS [bigint]
    START WITH 410014104
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 410000000
    MAXVALUE 419999999
    CYCLE 
    CACHE 
  GO
  ```
- I don't have a Unique Constraint (but I plan to put one on).  However that will only help me know when I have reused a value.  Not what caused the values to reset.  I put a job on that would get a new value every 5 min an save it off.  The times and value jumps do not follow a pattern.
- I have checked the Event Logs to see if there is an error.  The only think that is happening is this:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2793634  We are applying the fix today.  I don't think these are related, but it could be.

Comment: Why isn't there a PK or Unique constraint on this column? With that in place, this reuse will get caught, and you don't have to try to guess where it's coming from, unless your application code just swallows all errors...

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1395798-3077-1.aspx

Comment: Can you show the definition of your sequence? Also can you check the error log to see if any significant events happened overnight (e.g. failover, service restart, memory issues, etc)?

Comment: What is `@@VERSION`? Also has anything changed about the environment? There is [a connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/790161/next-value-for-sequence-can-fail-to-return-proper-next-value) reporting something similar. The OP there reckons it was associated with `11.0.3000.0`

Comment: If this bug is real (and it looks like it) this is a scary concurrency bug.

Comment: @MartinSmith I dug into this a bit - while the MSDN thread seems to imply that instances on RTM were affected but not ones on later builds, I could find no evidence of any publicly documented fix in the list of fixes for SP1, SP2 or any of the RTM CUs. In fact the only mention of sequence across all 2012 fixes to date that I could find (and seems unrelated) is [in SP2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2958429) VSTS #1347204. This doesn't mean it's not a bug, just that it may not be fixed intentionally, may not affect that instance for another reason, or the fix kept private for reasons unknown.

Comment: @AaronBertrand And the Connect Item doesn't have many votes so presumably can't be a common issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith I have a naked 2012 RTM instance and I'll try to repro this hopefully later today. I suspect there is some other environmental factor that has to be in place for the sequence to lose its mind like that (and I agree that the low vote count is likely evidence that this isn't common).

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I updated my question with answers to your comments.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I updated my question with an answer to your comment.

Comment: Why do you have it set to CYCLE?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Well, these values used to come from a legacy system that was just an Int.  We did "Cycle" when it hit mid 10 digit range.  I just kept that in there.  As a BIGINT, the cycle is not really going to happen during my time at our company.  I could take it off.  (It should not have any effect on this issue though right?)

Comment: Well, CYCLE essentially tells SQL Server you are okay with reusing values. I have absolutely no idea *why* you're having this issue, and don't know that you'll find out why (how much time do you spend investigating why you got a flat tire, before you just replace it?). I still think your best bet is to have a constraint there to prevent duplicates, and to turn off caching in hopes of preventing reuse.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - I agree.  I am going to give the NO CACHE thing a go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, if you don't want duplicates in this column, **state that explicitly**.

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.whatever ADD CONSTRAINT uq_that_column UNIQUE (that_column);
```

(Or you may want to make that the primary key, or change the clustered index, or what have you...)

In any case, raising an error when you generate a duplicate is far better than just blindly inserting a duplicate that you'll just have to deal with later.

Next, consider that a SEQUENCE is just a number generator, and by default it has a cache of 50 values. Depending on how your transactions are set up, and what other critical events happen on a server, it is possible that SQL Server can "forget" that it generated certain values for you.

There was a bug on Connect (790161) before they eradicated Connect, that talked about these duplicate values, but it seems to have been addressed in this fix (thanks @Andomar):

- KB #3011465
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011465

> FIX: Sequence object generates duplicate sequence values when SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 is under memory pressure
>
> Assume that you create a sequence object that has the CACHE option
> enabled in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014. When the
> instance is under memory pressure, and multiple concurrent connections
> request sequence values from the same sequence object, duplicate
> sequence values may be generated. In addition, a unique or primary key
> (PK) violation error occurs when the duplicate sequence value is
> inserted into a table.

A way to get around this (if that fix doesn't solve your issue, or you are stuck on an ancient and unsupported build without the fix) is to change the sequence to use `NO CYCLE` and `NO CACHE`, e.g.:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE dbo.mysequence NO CYCLE NO CACHE;
```

Note that `NO CACHE` can affect performance and concurrency, but will help eliminate gaps, lost blocks and, who knows, maybe your problem too.

Comment: Well, I can't have it backing up.  So if NO CACHE will fix it, then that is what I will do.

Comment: I thought that there may be transactions causing this.  But the Sequence page on MSDN says "Sequence numbers are generated outside the scope of the current transaction. They are consumed whether the transaction using the sequence number is committed or rolled back."  So I discarded my transaction theory. I agree there must be something else going on.

Comment: Turns out that just setting it with `NO CYCLE` was enough.  (At least it did not happen last night.)  Thank you for the help!

Comment: [FIX: Sequence object generates duplicate sequence values when SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014 is under memory pressure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3011465) Assume that you create a sequence object that has the CACHE option enabled in Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server 2014. When the instance is under memory pressure, and multiple concurrent connections request sequence values from the same sequence object, duplicate sequence values may be generated. In addition, a unique or primary key (PK) violation error occurs when the duplicate sequence value is inserted into a table.